# REGEX, searching for emails with a certain defined length, prefix & domain? (attempted but failed)

Tags: regex, search, full-text-search

Hi i'm doing some infosec research and searching through text bins.

I'm using a text editor to search files and I'm wanting to search for email addresses with certain conditions. Text is comma-separated.

Say for example i know the email is 20 chars long and I know that the domain is gmail.com, and I also know it starts with t.

```
[tT](.{9})@gmail.com
```

If it was correct it should pick up for example: tqwertyuio@gmail.com   and tzxcvb1234@gmail.com. Right?

I'm using emEditor which uses Boost Regex engine I think. This regex is just not working as it also returns anything that has that expression in it.

I've tried to use anchors, but they are not working. Perhaps its this engine. I would of thought i would go:

```
^[tT](.{9})@gmail.com$
```

But it's not working. Any help?? Thanks SO much i really just want to learn why i cant do this.

Comment: It depends if the text editor search and replace feature is regex based and what regex flavor it is.

Comment: hi Wiktor. Just want to search and extract - no replacing. What do you suggest then moving text editor? Is that REGEX right???

Comment: `[tT](.{9})@gmail.com` will match strings like `t123456789@gmail.com`, `t12 456 89@gmail.com` etc. in Notepad++.

Comment: this is better regex: [tT]\S{9}@gmail\.com - \S avoid spaces and \. will must '.' not every char, look in https://regex101.com/ is good online regex tester

Comment: Still havent found a solution. Tried those out and it doesnt work in my reg tester :(

Comment: If it helps apparently its based of Perl regular expression syntax. http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_search_regexp_syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for 20 characters long email which are NOT surrounded by alphabets or numbers. In that case, you can search for:

`(?<!\w)[tT](.{9})@gmail.com(?!\w)`

where `\w` is an alphabet or a number, `(?<!\w)` is negative lookbehind, and `(?!\w)` is negative lookahead.

In the **Find** dialog box, you can enter this regular expression, and make sure you select the "Regular Expressions" option.

[image]

You might also want to try the **Filter** toolbar with the same regular expression.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yutaka, due to some CSV errors this was the case! Also thanks SO much for a great product.